# How do I activate the AJP port on Wildfly 11?

Tags: http, configuration, jboss, wildfly, ajp

I just installed Wildfly 11.0.0.Final on Amazon Linux with Java 8.  How do I activate the AJP port in the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file  ?  I have the following configured for my socket bindings ...

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <!-- <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/> -->
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8081}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

However when I restart my server, although I'm able to connect to the http port, I can't connect to the AJP port ...

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ telnet localhost 8081
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
quit
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close

Connection closed by foreign host.
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ telnet localhost 8009
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

What else do I need to do to activate my AJP port on Wildfly 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to activate it.  See [AJP Listeners](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/AJP+listeners) for a bit more detail but the short answer is that you need to enable it:

`[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/ajp-listener=myListener:add(socket-binding=ajp, scheme=http, enabled=true)`

This uses `jboss-cli.sh` to enable it. In this case `myListener` is whatever name you want.  This will add an entry in the `undertow` section of standalone.xml that enables the listener.  You'll need to restart to have this take affect.